# Can I merge objects without messing up their modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, objects, edit-mode

I have made a character, through several different objects, using different modifiers for each of them. Is there a way that I can combine them into one object, without having the modifiers screwed with?

Comment: No. You will need to apply the modifiers

Answer (score 6):

Although some modifiers can be applied to specific parts of a mesh via vertex groups, when you join them you will find that the active object's modifiers always overwrites the others.

You will need to *apply* the modifiers before joining the meshes, or add them afterwards using vertex grouping. Sadly you will not be able to edit the modifiers after applying, but they will not be messed up by joining.

Comment: Actually you *can* apply some modifiers to specific mesh sections by means of vertex groups etc. Mask, displace to name a few.